# How to specify iCE40 package when using Arachne-PNR

Tags: fpga, synthesis, softcore

I am trying to synthesise the [picorv32](https://github.com/cliffordwolf/picorv32/tree/master/picosoc) [picosoc](https://github.com/cliffordwolf/picorv32/tree/master/picosoc) for an [IceFun board](https://www.robotshop.com/ca/en/icefun-fpga-board.html).

So far, I have cloned the HX8Kdemo files, and modified the Makefile and PCF files accordingly.

When I try to run 'make icefun' I get an error:

```
icefun.pcf:11 fatal error: unknown pin 'A3' on package 'ct256'
```

Presumably, the problem is that the HX8K demo is designed for the ct256 package, while the IceFun board used the cb132 package.

**Question:** What do I need to modify to tell the toolchain that I am using the cb132 package? Is this specified in a file somewhere or as a comand line parameter to Arachne-PNR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Arachne-pnr package can be set using the `-P` option, i.e. `arachne-pnr -P cb132` should work. (this information was kindly provided by `man arachne-pnr` on debian.)